# Porting a new feature of latest GCC into an older GCC version

Tags: gcc

I have been trying to port an upgraded **Address Sanitizer** feature from **GCC-7.3.0** compiler to an older version of **gcc(GCC-4.8.1)**. Though I found success in replacing the entire library with its dependencies to the older version, the compiler **front end** also seems to have changed a lot between the versions. So before I actually go and proceed with the changes in the front end also, I thought I'd ask, Can it be done without changing other behaviors of the GCC 4.8.1? And is it too much effort? TIA.

Comment: It's probably not worth the trouble. What use case do you have where using gcc-7.3 isn't an option?

Comment: Development environment has been using gcc-4.8. So, they are not willing to take a bet on changing the compiler as they are not sure on how the existing code would function, for the next code release is around the corner.

Comment: You are not planning to use ASAN in production anyway, are you?

Comment: No, it's to be used at the development site alone

Comment: Then trying out gcc-7.3 just as an experiment at the dev site is not taking a bet.